# jquery javascript  css issue - inline font weight manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little slideshow that I am trying to implement in a Sharepoint site. I have the show working, however, not to my total satisfaction.

The 'problem' smippet of code that I have (admittedly) used this from the internets:

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
        var imageLink = imageURL+$(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").substring($(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").indexOf('#')+1);
  var itemLink = itemURL+$(this).attr("ows_ID");
  var liHtml = "<div><img width='200' height='200'  src='" + imageLink +"'/><p align='center'>"+ title + "</p></div>";
```

However, I would like the var title to be of: a. heavier font-weight (500), and b. lesser line-height.

I've tried a bunch of things that don't work. I tried giving the

element in this part of the code:

```
> var liHtml = "<div><img width='200' height='200'  src='" + imageLink
> +"'/><p align='center'>"+ title + "</p></div>";
```

its own id, and then tried manipulating that id with some jquery, no luck. I tried manipulating the var title when I declare the var, but no luck.

What is this dummy jquery newb missing?

**EDIT**

A little extra info that I probably should have included (I try to keep these things as short as possible, then realize I've missed pertinent information):

My understanding of CSS leads me to believe that I can have css in 3 places: separate style sheet, in the head of the doc, or inline. I can't put anything in the document head, because I am doing this all in a SP webpart. I tried making < p id="title_par" align='center'>, then maniputlate the $("#title_par").css with jquery, but no luck. Also, tried to do it inline, with , but that didn't work either.
So basically, I have no access to the .css file (I have no Sharpoint designer to work with, I only have Site Collection admin privileges)

Comment: Ouch, the code from the internets needs to learn CSS.

Comment: This is a CSS problem, not jQuery and not JavaScript specific. Retaged for better answers.

Comment: What are you doing with those var in the each() ?

Comment: Grabbing the urls for all of the images inside the Sharepoint picture library.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you use 'liHtml' for example ?

Comment: $("#slideshowContentArea").append(liHtml);
    });
  
$("#slideshowContentArea").css("display", "block");

$('#slideshowContentArea').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    timeout: 10000,
    delay:  -3000
});
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be resolved with CSS.

Add a class to the `<p align='center'>` like `<p align='center' class='classOfTitle'>`  to style it via CSS and use:

```
.classOfTitle {
     line-height: 1em; /* you can use any units */
     font-weight: bold; /* font-weight in units isn't suported by all browsers (the standars are inherit, bold and normal */
}
```

Comment: Pardon me for sounding stupid, but, here goes..... My understanding of CSS leads me to believe that I can have css in 3 places: separate style sheet, in the head of the doc, or inline. I can't put anything in the document head, because I am doing this all in a SP webpart. I tried making < p id="title_par" align='center'>, then maniputlate the $("#title_par").css with jquery, but no luck. Also, tried to do it inline (option 3), with <p style="font-weight:500" align = 'center'>, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Why don't you put the text-align in the CSS class ? ;-)

Comment: I can't access the CSS sheet (Sharepoint). If I could access it, I would actually be able to this, even at my novice level (that is meant to be read as self-deprecating, not in any way rude to you, btw)

Comment: I was asking this to rcdmk, not to you, sorry... Btw If <p style="some style..."> doesn't works nothing could... it's crazy man ;-)

Comment: @mrwienerdog Does it work with: `<p align='center' style='line-height: 1em; font-weight: bold; margin: 0;'>`? I think paragaph margins are creating more space and you think is `line-height`.

Comment: @Valky I could add the `text-align` to the style with no problem, but I simply ignored it, since its not the focus of the question. Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @rcdmk thanks! I realized when I looked at your last comment that I was putting double quotes inside double quotes (dummy). So I made sure that my inline styles were in singles, and now it is fine. Great!

Answer (score 2):

It is a CSS problem, not Jquery.

Try this

// Your js

```
var liHtml = "<div><img width='200' height='200'  src='" + imageLink +"'/>
<p class='title'>"+ title + "</p></div>";
```

// Your css file

```
.title {text-align:center;font-weight:500;line-height:10px;}
```